# Setting up radio button click ActionListeners

Tags: java, event-handling, gui

Instead of writing four almost identical `setOnClickListener` method calls, I opted to iterate over an array, but I'm wondering if this was the best way to do it. Do you have any suggestions for improving it?

```
/* Set up the radio button click listeners so two categories are not selected
   at the same time. When one of them is clicked it clears the others.
*/
final RadioButton[] buttons = {radio_books,radio_games,radio_dvds,radio_electronics};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    final int k = i;
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (buttons[j] != buttons[k]) {
                    buttons[j].setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: One thing I'd recommend is to use lowerCamelCase for variable names. That's the variable naming convention for Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What GUI framework is this? Is the `View v` being passed to the `OnClick` method actually the clicked `RadioButton`? If so, here are some changes to consider

```
final RadioButton[] buttons = {radio_books,radio_games,radio_dvds,radio_electronics};

final OnClickListener onClickHandler =
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final RadioButton checkedButton = (RadioButton) v;
            for (final RadioButton button : buttons) {
                if (button != checkedButton) {
                    button.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };

for (final RadioButton button : buttons) {
    button.setOnClickListener(onClickHandler);
}
```

If `View v` != the checked radio button, then:

```
final RadioButton[] buttons = {radio_books,radio_games,radio_dvds,radio_electronics};
for (final RadioButton thisButton: buttons) {
    thisButton.setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                for (final RadioButton button : buttons) {
                    if (button != thisButton) {
                        button.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Why are you still looping over the button array in the listener in your first solution?

Comment: @Paul - Because he's trying to uncheck the buttons that were not the clicked one, so it loops to get to all the buttons and uses the if to exclude the one that was clicked.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Paul - lol - its 1:24am here - I risking misread the code myself, so I understand the feeling. Actually, thanks for reminding me of the time :-) need sleep ...

Comment: It's the android GUI framework. The RadioGroup that handles the boilerplate of making sure only one radio button is active at a time failed on me because I need a layout that was a bit more complicated.

Comment: Also, I like your take on using the View passed into the onClick method and I'll see if I can get away with not having `final int k = i`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I think with the improved 'for' loops and using the View argument of onClick to perform the exclusion it can't be improved further.

Answer (score 2):

It's typical callback method, you just **defined** `setOnClickListener` once. Calling 4 times is not bad [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).